# Format text in a Masked TextBox

Tags: c#, string, format, maskedtextbox

I have a masked text box that is used to show today's date, like this:

```
txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

However it can still be edited to change the date. Being a masked text box, the only worry is if someone wants to add the date like so:

```
27/1/15
```

Is there a way I can edit this to add the additional information and automatically format it to this? Possibly using `String.Format` perhaps?

```
27/01/2015
```

**EDIT:** To clarify, When the form opens, the `txtDate` will automatically receive today's date, but if a user wants to change the date, how can I ensure that the date will remain in the right format? I.e. dd/MM/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

string str = String.Format("{0:00}/{1:00}/{2:0000}", d.Month, d.Day, d.Year);
```

Edit:

You can add `days`, `months`, `years`... to your variable of type `DateTime` `d`

Example:

```
d = DateTime.Now;
d = d.AddDays(5);  // add 5 days to current date
```

**EDIT2**

Say you have 3 textBoxes `txtDays`, `txtMonth` and `txtYear`

```
int year = Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Text);
int month = Convert.ToInt32(txtMonth.Text);
int days = Convert.ToInt32(txtDays.Text);

// you can assign any date as follows:
DateTime d = new DateTime(year, month, days);
```

Or if the users will have only one textBox called `txtDate` and they have to enter the date in the form "MM/dd/yyyy":

```
var[] date = txtDate.Split('/');
txtDate.Text = String.Format("{0:00}/{1:00}/{2:0000}", date[0], date[1], date[2]);
```

Comment: I guess because the text won't change until tomorrow :) use another way to debug and see the text of `txtDate`

Comment: This only returns the current date (`DateTime.Now`) so should I use just `DateTime` instead? and what method should I add it to? `TextChanged` won't work, is there one for when a user tabs out of the text box?

Comment: But you said `I have a masked text box that is used to show today's date, like this:` ?!

Comment: can you please elaborate more on when you want to update your `txtDate.text` ?

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. I have intentionally left it enabled, so that users *can* enter a different date.

Comment: still don't really get you, but I guess my last edit is almost what you want